# Parsing HTML into iText Elements while using XMLWorker

Tags: java, itext

I have a need to create iText Element(s) (or Chunk(s)) that contain HTML. The HTML in part of a HTML document that is parsed into a PDF using the XMLWorker. I've tried using a class that extends the AbstractTagProcessor, but I don't get anything back in the final PDF document. Not sure if this is even possible. Here is the code I'm using:

```
  class Narrative extends AbstractTagProcessor implements TagProcessor {

    @Override
    public List<com.itextpdf.text.Element> end(WorkerContext ctx, Tag tag, List<com.itextpdf.text.Element> currentContent) {
        List<com.itextpdf.text.Element> l = new ArrayList<com.itextpdf.text.Element>();

        for (com.itextpdf.text.Element element : currentContent) {
            try {
                ElementList parsed = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(element.getChunks().get(0).getContent(), readCSS());
                for(com.itextpdf.text.Element elem : parsed) {
                    l.add(elem);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return l;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
I think I found the solution. I'm posting it so other may not have to go through what I wen through to find the solution. Feedback welcomed.

```
class Narrative extends Div implements TagProcessor {
    private PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

    public Narrative() {
        table.setTotalWidth(650f);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100f);
        table.setKeepTogether(true);
        table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(0);
    }

    @Override
    public List<com.itextpdf.text.Element> end(WorkerContext ctx, Tag tag, List<com.itextpdf.text.Element> currentContent) {
        List<com.itextpdf.text.Element> content = new ArrayList<Element>();
        try {
            content = HTMLWorker.parseToList(new StringReader(currentContent.get(0).getChunks().get(0).getContent()), null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(com.itextpdf.text.Element c : content) {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.setBorder(0);
            cell.addElement(c);
            table.addCell(cell);
        }

        List<com.itextpdf.text.Element> l = new ArrayList<Element>();
        l.add(table);
        return l;
}
```

Comment: Research "Recursive Descent Parser".  Basically, when you encounter HTML inside HTML you recurse.